# set visibility of jqgrid colum through function return value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i have a jqgrid, and i want to set the column visibility through a function return value
this is what i have tried

```
 colModel: [{ name: 'TypeId', index: 'TypeId', label: 'Type Id', sortable: true, hidden:$.mns.getcolvisiblity() },
            {..rest of cols}


 $.mns=
 {
  getcolvisiblity:function()
  {
   if(mycondition)
    {
      return true;
     }
    else
     {
     return false;
      }
```

i have put a breakpoint and tested, and i am sure it is returning true or false based on conditon but my column will always be hidden

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders:thanks,so now i am sure on what mistake not to make next time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colModel: [{ name: 'TypeId', index: 'TypeId', label: 'Type Id', sortable: true, hidden:false },//make hidden false by default
 {..rest of cols}

```
  $.mns=
  {
   getcolvisiblity:function()
  {
    if(mycondition)
     {
       $("#gridname").hideCol("colname")
     }
    else
     {
       //do nothing as column is already visible 
     }
  }
 },
```

and in document ready call this function.

Comment: i came up with this solution.if there is any other simple way to accomplish this, then the answer is welcome!